# Summarizing proportionally with a buffer and polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, overlapping-features

I have two polygon layer in ArcGIS pro, a kind of polygon raster and a layer with several overlapping buffer. The first has attributes like number of inhabitants or age groups.

[image: Both layers]

I would like to intersect the buffers with the first layer. Depending on the percentage of cells that are inside the buffer, attributes should be merged. For example, if 50% of a cell with 10 inhabitants and 10% of a cell with 40 inhabitants is inside a buffer, 9 (5+4) inhabitants should be assigned to the buffer in a new table. The example is of course much larger because of the 8 cells.

For example, I experimented with the tool "summarize within". But there I get as result only the added number of inhabitants of the whole cell. I thought about to clip the cells, but then I got only the area of the buffer. Is there another tool or way that I have overlooked?

[image: Attribute table of summarize within]